# how to target part of gatling test with a specific load profile

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I have a Gatling test that is divided into 3 sections:

1. beforeTest() - where entity under test is created
2. test() - where some functionality is tested. E.g, entity is modified, child dependent entities are created, etc.
3. afterTest() - cleanup, entity under test is deleted

Base class - should be overridden for implementing

```
    trait BaseTest extends Simulation {
    
       def beforeTest() : ScenarioBuilder = scenario("empty before")

       def test(): ScenarioBuilder

       def afterTest() : ScenarioBuilder = scenario("empty after")


       setUp(
 
         scenario(getClass.getSimpleName)
          .exec(beforeTest())
          .exec(test())
          .exec(afterTest())
          .inject(loadProfile)

       )
    
    }
```

**My question:
How can target only test() with load profile, i.e. exclude beforeTest() and afterTest()?
The motivation: I need to do beforeTest and afterTest only once, where performance testing should focus on test().
BUT!! I still want to use Gatling DSL for beforeTest() and afterTest()
any idea?**

**Note**: I'm using Gatling 3.0.3